# Trouble using triangle strips in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es

I'd like to render a full-screen aligned mesh using `TRIANGLE_STRIP`s. It consists of 9 vertices and 8 triangles, and should look something like:

```
A----B----C
| 1 /| 3 /|
|  / |  / |
| /  | /  |
|/ 2 |/ 4 |
D----E----F
| 5 /| 7 /|
|  / |  / |
| /  | /  |
|/ 6 |/ 8 |
G----H----I
```

Vertex `A` has the coordinates (-1, -1, 0), while vertex `I` is at (1, 1, 0). One might also say that this consists of 9 vertices positioned in 3 columns and 3 rows.

I'm trying to do this using the `TRIANGLE_STRIP` mode.

The indices that I supply to `glDrawElements` are as follows:

```
AD BE CF F
DG EH FI I
```

The `CFF` actually should produce a degenerated triangle so that one could skip to the next line.

What I'm having trouble with is calculating the right number to provide to `glDrawElements`. I'm doing it like that:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS, number_of_elelments,
    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, buffer);
```

First I though it should be the number of visible triangles:

```
number_of_elements = 2 * (cols - 1) * (rows - 1); // 8
```

But it was rendering half the the rectangles.

Then I remembered the degenerated rectangles and decided to include them, too:

```
number_of_elements = 2 * (cols - 1) * (rows - 1) + rows; // 10
```

It rendered more rectangles but still not all.

Then I tred by trial and error to guess what `number_of_elements` should be, and I could get all rectangles to be shown, so I think it's not a problem with the rest of the setup.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that I should've provided the number of *vertices*, not *triangles*. Anybody to confirm this? In the OpenGL spec they said *count of elements*, and as the elements were triangles, I thought it was triangles, but it very much seems that I've been mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your comment is correct and you have to provide the number of indices and not triangles. To clarify terms, an element is not a triangle and neither a vertex, it's an index (or a vertex referenced by an index).

Furthermore your drawing order is broken, anyway. You not only have to repeat F, but also D (introducing 4 instead of just 2 degenerate triangles), otherwise you will get a triangle with vertices F, D and G (which you don't want). But on the other hand you don't need to repeat I (if you don't have another row). So your rendering order would be something like:

```
AD BE CF F
D DG EH FI
```

But to figure out how to automize this in a loop depending on the number of rows and columns is your task now.

Comment: Are you sure about that I need to repeat D? For I don't seem to see anything incorrect in the output...

Comment: @Albus When you don't draw textures or any lighting, but only flat colored faces, it may be that the wrong FDG (or DFG, don't know) triangle is just rendered over the correct triangles. But it's just wrong, at least when you enable things like textureing, lighting or anything giving more structure than a single flat color.

Comment: Yes, I'm texturing the triangles. I'll look into it a bit more. Triangle strips is a new subject to me so sorry if sound ignorant.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore It may also be that this incorrect triangle is culled away by back-face culling or does get overwritten by the correct ones (when the depth func is `GL_LEQUAL`), but believe me, it is there. A triangle strip renders a new triangle for **every** vertex after the 2nd.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore It may also be that texturing alone (without any lighting or non-uniform coloring) will not result in artefacts, since the wrong triangle uses the same texCoords as the correct ones. But in such a case you don't need a complex triangle strip and a simple 4-vertex quad-like tri-strip would do, anyway.

Comment: You were 100% right. After trying with some larger textures I noticed some funny artifacts, just like *stripes* of textures that shouldn't be there. It's perfect now. Thanks *very* much. Highly obliged!